# Lindenmayer (L-Systems) colouring individual units

Tags: tikz-pgf

I use the following code to produce Lindenmayer drawings, utilizing the code from [this site](http://paulbourke.net/fractals/lsys/).

Is it possible to modify this code to colour each individual unit with a different colour, producing the last picture?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}
\usetikzlibrary[shadings]
\begin{document}
{
\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{Pntaplx}{
\rule{F -> F++F++F+++++F-F++F}
}
\foreach \k in {0,1}
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,rotate=0]
\draw[draw=red!80!black, fill=yellow, line width=0.1cm, line cap=round, lindenmayer system={Pntaplx, axiom=F++F++F++F++F, order=\k, angle=36, step=.4cm}] lindenmayer system;
\end{tikzpicture}
}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: One of the challenges of your approach is that the small pentagons are not really separately closed paths, because the L-system just makes one long line -- albeit a line that goes back on itself and touches at the corners.  So when you fill it, you can only fill the whole thing...   A recursive approach might give you more flexibility.  Is that any good?

Comment: @Thruston Thank you for your explanatory comment.

Comment: This is a so-called *Iterative Fractal System (IFS)*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not an L-system -- but it does show a recursive approach to drawing a [pentaflake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-flake) that allows you to play with the colouring.

[image]

I have used [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) for the drawing, wrapped up in `luamplib`, so you need to compile it with `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
input colorbrewer-rgb
vardef median(expr p) = origin for i=1 upto 5: + 1/5 point i of p endfor enddef;
vardef flake(expr level, limit, p, s) = 
    if level < 1:
        fill p withcolor s;
        draw p withcolor 3/4 s;  % or omit the colour to get the default black
    else:
        save small_p, m;
        path small_p; pair m; m = median(p); 
        small_p = p shifted -m scaled 0.381966; % (phi/(phi+1+phi)) \simeq 0.381966 
        for i=1 upto 5:
            flake(level - 1, limit, small_p shifted (point i of p - point i of small_p), 
            if level = limit: Spectral[6][i] else: s fi);
        endfor
        flake(level - 1, limit, small_p rotated 180 shifted m, 
            if level = limit: Spectral 6 6 else: s fi);
    fi
enddef;
beginfig(1);
    path P; P = for i=1 upto 5: 50 up rotated 72i -- endfor cycle;
    for j=1, 2, 3:
        for i=1 upto j+1:
            picture T; 
            T = image(
                flake(j, i, P, 15/16);
                label("$(" & decimal j & "," & decimal i & ")$", 
                    point 1/2 of bbox currentpicture + 6 down);
            );
            draw T shifted (100j-100i, 110j);
        endfor
    endfor
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

### Notes

Most of the code in the example above is devoted to playing with the colours.  For a basic pentaflake recursive procedure you could strip it back like this:

```
vardef flake(expr level, p) = 
    if level < 1:
        draw p;
    else:
        save small_p, m;
        path small_p; pair m; 
        m = median(p);   
        small_p = p shifted -m scaled 0.381966; % (phi/(phi+1+phi)) \simeq 0.381966 
        flake(level - 1, small_p shifted (point 0 of p - point 0 of small_p));
        flake(level - 1, small_p shifted (point 1 of p - point 1 of small_p)); 
        flake(level - 1, small_p shifted (point 2 of p - point 2 of small_p)); 
        flake(level - 1, small_p shifted (point 3 of p - point 3 of small_p)); 
        flake(level - 1, small_p shifted (point 4 of p - point 4 of small_p)); 
        flake(level - 1, small_p rotated 180 shifted m);
    fi
enddef;
```

The approach here is to define the routine with a `level` parameter and a pentagon `p` to draw.  When the level is less than 1, just draw the path `p`.  Otherwise, call `flake` again with a scaled-down and shifted copy of `p` -- called `small_p`, and with the level set to `level-1`.   This is a nice simple way to do recursion in MP.

You could then use this routine in a complete program like this:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
vardef median(expr p) = origin for i=1 upto 5: + 1/5 point i of p endfor enddef;
vardef flake(expr level, p) = 
    ... as above ...
enddef;
beginfig(1);
    path P; P = for i=1 upto 5: 100 up rotated 72i -- endfor cycle;
    flake(3, P);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Compiling this with `lualatex` would produce this:

[image]

And you could play about with this to make variations. For example if you comment out the sixth call to `flake` that puts the shape in the middle, then you get this gasket instead:

[image]

Note that in order to get the scaling and rotation right it helps to shift the shape back to the origin, then scale it and rotate it, then shift it back to where it is wanted.  And note that to get this right you can't use the built-in `center` command because that gives you the centre of the bounding box of the shape, not the actual median of the shape (ie the centre of the circle through the five points of the shape).

You could also put the first five calls into a loop as shown in the multicoloured example.  The rest of the complexity is just dealing with the colours.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I applied your code; and I will try to understand it. Just one comment; can the line (draw p withcolor s;) be modified to specify a particular colour instead of drawing with the fill colour, which does not show the drawing if white colour is applied?

Comment: yes, you could do `draw p withcolor 1/2s` which would give you a dark version of the fill colour.  See updated drawing.

Comment: @ Thruston Thank you very much for your time and effort. I will look deeper on your new code and comments.

Comment: @ Thruston Where the line flake(3, P) should be inserted.

Comment: Let me make that a bit more obvious -- you might like to follow the link at the top for  introductions and tutorials and the manual...

Comment: @ Thruston Thank you very very much for your time and patience. I applied your edited code, and got the result you specified. I will read the documents in the link at the top.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

This was the result of my original answer.  Since the OP asked if the pic element could be used in a recursive construction, see [Drawing recursive polygons in Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/685076/drawing-recursive-polygons-in-tikz), I indicate one possibility below.

[image]
Using the recursive pic element `p rec` which takes three arguments: recursion step, end, angle.

[image]
Using the recursive pic element `p* rec` which takes three arguments: recursion step, end, angle.

[image]
`end = 3`, `4`, and `5` respectively

[image]
`end = 3` and `color mixing = 2`, `4`, and `6` respectively

*Remark*. There are two global parameters, the radius of the initial pentagon, the degree of color mixing inside an elementary pentagon (the initial drawing corresponds to a maximal color mixing, `indCM=6`), and a counter, `pCnt`.

**New version of the answer**

```
\documentclass[11pt, border=.8cm]{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, math}
\begin{document}


\newcounter{pCnt}
\newcommand{\chooseRGB}[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{0}}{\colorlet{RGB}{red}}{}  
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1}}{\colorlet{RGB}{yellow!90!red!90!blue}}{}
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{2}}{\colorlet{RGB}{orange}}{}
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{3}}{\colorlet{RGB}{green!60!black}}{}
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{4}}{\colorlet{RGB}{blue}}{}
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{5}}{\colorlet{RGB}{violet}}{}
}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
  indexColorMixing/.store in=\indCM,
  indexColorMixing = 1
}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
  pentagonRadius/.store in=\pentagonR,
  pentagonRadius = 2
}
\tikzset{
  pentagons/.style={%
    evaluate={%
      real \pentagonAngle, \pentagonCst, \pentagonCstRecursion;
      \pentagonAngle = 72;
      \pentagonCst = {2*cos(\pentagonAngle/2)};
      \pentagonCstRecursion = {1/(1 +\pentagonCst))};
    }
  },
  pics/pentagon/.style 2 args={% 
    code={%
      \draw[#1, ultra thick, fill=#2] (0: \pentagonR)
      \foreach \i in {1, ..., 4}{%
        -- (\i*\pentagonAngle: \pentagonR)
      } -- cycle;
    }
  },
  pics/p rec/.style n args={3}{% recursion step, end, angle
    code={%
      \tikzmath{
        integer \i;
        \i = #1+1;
        if \i<#2 then {%
          \tmp = {\pentagonR*pow(\pentagonCstRecursion, \i)*\pentagonCst};
          {
            \path pic {p rec={\i}{#2}{#3 +180}};
          };
          for \j in {0, ..., 4}{%
            {
              \path (#3 +\j*\pentagonAngle: \tmp)
              pic {p rec={\i}{#2}{#3 +\j*\pentagonAngle}};
            };
          };
        } else {%
          \tmp = {\pentagonR*pow(\pentagonCstRecursion, \i-1)};
          {%
            \draw (#3: \tmp)
            \foreach \k in {1, ..., 4}{%
              -- (#3 +\k*\pentagonAngle: \tmp)
            } -- cycle;
          };
        };
      }
    }
  },
  pics/p* rec/.style n args={3}{% recursion step, end, angle
    code={%
      \tikzmath{
        integer \i, \rgb;
        \i = #1+1;
        if \i<#2 then {%
          \tmp = {\pentagonR*pow(\pentagonCstRecursion, \i)*\pentagonCst};
          {
            \path pic {p* rec={\i}{#2}{#3 +180}};
          };
          for \j in {0, ..., 4}{%
            {
              \path (#3 +\j*\pentagonAngle: \tmp)
              pic {p* rec={\i}{#2}{#3 +\j*\pentagonAngle}};
            };
          };
        } else {%
          \tmp = {\pentagonR*pow(\pentagonCstRecursion, \i-1)};
          \rgb = int(mod(int(\thepCnt/(7 -\indCM)), 6));
          {%
            \chooseRGB{\rgb}
            \draw[white, fill=RGB] (#3: \tmp)
            \foreach \k in {1, ..., 4}{%
              -- (#3 +\k*\pentagonAngle: \tmp)
            } -- cycle;
            \stepcounter{pCnt}
          };
        };
      }
    }
  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[pentagons, pentagonRadius=1.3,
  evaluate={%
    \t=\pentagonAngle;
    \d = \pentagonCst*\pentagonR;
    \tini=30;}]
  \foreach \j/\rgb in
  {0/violet, 1/red, 2/orange, 3/green!70!black, 4/cyan!70!black}{%
    \path (\tini +\j*\t +\t/2: \d) pic[rotate={\tini +\t/2}]
    {pentagon={\rgb}{\rgb!30}};
  }
  \path (0, 0) pic[rotate=\tini] {pentagon={blue}{blue!35}};
  \path (7, 0) node[scale=1.3, text width=15ex]
  {Elementary drawing using a {\color{blue}pic} element};
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}[pentagons, evaluate={\r=2;}]
  \path (0, 0) pic[blue] {p rec={0}{1}{0}};
  \path (5, 0) pic[blue] {p rec={0}{2}{20}};
  \path (10, 0) pic[blue] {p rec={0}{3}{-20}};
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}[pentagons]
  \setcounter{pCnt}{0}
  \path (0, 0) pic {p* rec={0}{1}{0}};
  \setcounter{pCnt}{0}
  \path (5, 0) pic {p* rec={0}{2}{10}};
  \setcounter{pCnt}{0}
  \path (10, 0) pic {p* rec={0}{3}{10}};
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}[pentagons]
  \setcounter{pCnt}{0}
  \path (0, 0) pic {p* rec={0}{3}{0}};
  \setcounter{pCnt}{0}
  \path (5, 0) pic {p* rec={0}{4}{0}};
  \setcounter{pCnt}{0}
  \path (10, 0) pic {p* rec={0}{5}{10}};
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}[pentagons]
  \setcounter{pCnt}{0}
  \path[indexColorMixing=2] (0, 0) pic {p* rec={0}{3}{0}};
  \setcounter{pCnt}{0}
  \path[indexColorMixing=4] (5, 0) pic {p* rec={0}{3}{0}};
  \setcounter{pCnt}{0}
  \path[indexColorMixing=6] (10, 0) pic {p* rec={0}{3}{10}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Original answer**

One way would be to draw the pentagons directly; I tried to use a `pic` element and a loop.  The `pic` element named `pentagon` takes two arguments, the edge color and the inner color.  By default, it has a vertex on the `Ox` axis.

The size of the pentagons is controlled by the variable `\a` defined at the beginning.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, border=.8cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, math}
\begin{document}

\tikzmath{
  real \a, \d, \t, \tini;
  \a = 2;  % radius
  \t = 72;
  \d = {2*\a*cos(\t/2)};  % distance between two centers 
  \tini = -90;  % initial angle
}
\tikzset{
  pics/pentagon/.style 2 args={%
    code={%
      \draw[#1, ultra thick, fill=#2] (0: \a)
      \foreach \i in {1, ..., 4}{ -- (\i*\t: \a) } -- cycle;
    }
  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \j/\rgb in
  {0/violet, 1/red, 2/orange, 3/green!70!black, 4/cyan!70!black}{%
    \path (\tini +\j*\t +\t/2: \d) pic[rotate={\t/4}]
    {pentagon={\rgb}{\rgb!30}};
  }
  \path (0, 0) pic[rotate=\tini] {pentagon={blue}{blue!35}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @ Daniel N I would like to thank you very much for your answer. I use your code to draw different kinds of polygons after editing this very useful code; when I do not need the Lindenmayer compound arrangement code by Thruston.  Unfortunately the system does not allow me to accept both answers.

Comment: @ Daniel N If it is possible to modify your tikz-based code to build the other multiple coloured arrangement drawings shown in Thruston answer, please let me know. I will post another question requesting this.

Comment: Hi @Hany !  I'm glad you can use the answer.  And forget about the voting system.  Concerning the second question, I have to think about it; it should be a recursive construction based on putting together five "elements" around a central one at each step.  Each element is constructed at the previous step...  I cannot promise to have an answer quickly though; in four or five days.

Comment: @ Daniel N Thank you for your concern. I will post my question, and I will tell you its url.

Comment: @ Daniel N This is the link to my posted question  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/685076/drawing-recursive-polygons-in-tikz

Comment: Hi @Hany.  I modified my previous answer here.  In your new question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/685076/drawing-recursive-polygons-in-tikz there is a difference between the drawings you are looking for (vertex to side contact) and @Thruston 's example your are providing (side to side contact).  I tried to use my original idea based on the pic element `pentagon` which was pushed towards recursion.  I included a color control key named `indexColorMixing`.

Comment: @ Daniel N I can not find the proper words to thank you enough for your kindness, time and concern. I would have chosen your answer; but this would be a vulgar behaviour since I have already chosen Thurston`s answer. I was hoping that you would have answered my posted 685076 question so that I could have chosen your answer.