# Drawing recursive polygons in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

To draw different kinds of polygons (with different rotations, scaling factors,...etc.), I use the following code (producing the top picture) modified from
[this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/684307/lindenmayer-l-systems-colouring-individual-units/684353#684353) to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/684307/lindenmayer-l-systems-colouring-individual-units/). The original code was designed to draw pentagons.

Is it possible to use a recursive construction approach, using TikZ, to produce something like the bottom picture from [this answer to the same post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/684307/lindenmayer-l-systems-colouring-individual-units/684370#684370). I have some difficulty understanding this perfect MetaPost code; and I get some undesirable results when modifying this very useful code to produce other polygons with different number of sides, and rotations.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, math}
\begin{document}
{
triangle4
\tikzmath{
real \a, \d, \t, \tini;
\a=2;
\t=120;
\d={2*\a*cos(\t/2)};
\tini=30;
}
\tikzset{
pics/triangl/.style 2 args={%
code={%
\draw[#1, line width=0.08cm, fill=#2] (0:\a)
\foreach \i in {0,...,2}{ -- (\i*\t:\a) } -- cycle;
}
}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.4, transform shape, opacity=.6]
\foreach \j/\rgb in
{0/violet, 1/red, 2/green!70!black}{%
\path (\tini+\j*\t+\t:\d\tini*2) pic[rotate={\tini*3}]
{triangl={\rgb}{\rgb!30}};
}
\path (0,0) pic[rotate=\tini] {triangl={blue}{blue!35}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
%
{
tetragon3
\tikzmath{
real \a, \d, \t, \tini;
\a=3;
\t=90;
\d={2*\a*cos(\t/2)};
\tini=22.5;
}
\tikzset{
pics/tetragon/.style 2 args={%
code={%
\draw[#1, line width=0.08cm, fill=#2] (0:\a)
\foreach \i in {0,...,3}{ -- (\i*\t:\a) } -- cycle;
}
}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.4, transform shape, rotate=\tini, opacity=.6]
\foreach \j/\rgb in
{0/violet, 1/red, 2/orange, 3/green!70!black}{%
\path (\tini+\j*\t+\t/2:\d*1.25) pic[rotate={\tini*3}]
{tetragon={\rgb}{\rgb!30}};
}
\path (0,0) pic[rotate=\tini] {tetragon={blue}{blue!35}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
%
{
hexagon4
\tikzmath{
real \a, \d, \t, \tini;
\a=2;
\t=60;
\d={2*\a*cos(\t/2)};
\tini=30;
}
\tikzset{
pics/hexagon/.style 2 args={%
code={%
\draw[#1, line width=0.08cm, fill=#2] (0:\a)
\foreach \i in {0,...,5}{ -- (\i*\t:\a) } -- cycle;
}
}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.4, transform shape, opacity=.6]
\foreach \j/\rgb in
{0/violet, 1/red, 2/orange, 3/green!70!black, 4/cyan!70!black, 5/brown!70!black}{%
\path (\tini+\j*\t+\t:\d*1.2) pic[rotate={\tini}]
{hexagon={\rgb}{\rgb!30}};
}
\path[scale=1.12] (0,0) pic[rotate=\tini*2] {hexagon={blue}{blue!35}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
%
{
octagon1-
\tikzmath{
real \a, \d, \t, \tini;
\a=2;
\t=45;
\d={2*\a*cos(\t/2)};
\tini=11.25;
}
\tikzset{
pics/octagon/.style 2 args={%
code={%
\draw[#1, line width=0.08cm, fill=#2] (0:\a)
\foreach \i in {0,...,7}{ -- (\i*\t:\a) } -- cycle;
}
}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.3, transform shape, opacity=.6]
\foreach \j/\rgb in
{0/violet, 1/red, 2/orange, 3/green!70!black, 4/cyan!70!black, 5/brown!70!black, 6/teal, 7/olive}{%
\path (\tini+\j*\t+\t*-.25:\d*1.45) pic[rotate={-\tini*2}]
{octagon={\rgb}{\rgb!30}};
}
\path[scale=1.88] (0,0) pic[rotate=\tini*2] {octagon={blue}{blue!35}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
{
octagon4-
\tikzmath{
real \a, \d, \t, \tini;
\a=2;
\t=45;
\d={2*\a*cos(\t/2)};
\tini=11.25;
}
\tikzset{
pics/octagon/.style 2 args={%
code={%
\draw[#1, line width=0.08cm, fill=#2] (0:\a)
\foreach \i in {0,...,7}{ -- (\i*\t:\a) } -- cycle;
}
}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.3, transform shape, opacity=.6]
\foreach \j/\rgb in
{0/violet, 1/red, 2/orange, 3/green!70!black, 4/cyan!70!black, 5/brown!70!black, 6/teal, 7/olive}{%
\path (\tini+\j*\t+\t*-.25:\d*1.35) pic[rotate={\tini*4}]
{octagon={\rgb}{\rgb!30}};
}
\path[scale=1.45] (0,0) pic[rotate=\tini*4] {octagon={blue}{blue!35}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have a draft for something like this that is similar to the TikZ solution of [another answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/661599). You only have to figure out the math portion.

Answer (score 14):

Okay, this is a generalization of [my TikZ/PGFKeys answer on the Sierpinski carpet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/661599). Instead of doing everything on one path (which allows for shading and clipping across the whole construct) this places a separate path for each *thing*.

This is also a recursive approach instead of `.scoped/.list` (which is just an ordinary `\foreach` I've realized) I'm using a `.foreach` handler which just loops through the given list and uses each value with the key.
Instead of `\pgfkeys{<key>/.foreach={<list>}}` we could have written `\foreach \item in {<list>}{\pgfkeys{<key>=\item}}`.

---

The first part only defines the algorithm, the looping and the recursion.
For each level a new drawing and shifting distance will be evaluated.

By default, nothing in the first part actually uses those.
It's your job to define `/tikz/flakes/stlying` and `/tikz/flakes/before do` in a way that uses the values `/tikz/flakes/drawDist` and `/tikz/flakes/shiftDist`.

Since your examples uses polygons, the `drawDist` is the radius of the circumference (i.e. the distance of each corner from the center). The `shiftDist` is the distance between the center of level *i* to the center of level *i*−1.
The ratio between two `drawDist`s is basically the scale factor for each recursion and needs to configures in the `draw to draw` key (which will be used by PGFmath down the line).

The function `draw to shift` is used to evaluate the previous `drawDist` to the next `shiftDist`.

---

For the polygons, I've added a second part that has some math figured out, in this case I'm defining the whole configuration for each polygon:

- the function `draw to draw` and `draw to shift`,
- the needed rotation for the center part and
- the needed shifting function.

Some of these can probably be generalized (think of functions `isodd` and `iseven`), maybe even the scaling factor.

Though, I see now that you have examples where the center has a different size than the satellites around it. I don't know how to approach this right now.
Notice however, that `before do` gets the item number given as `#1` (it's also available in `/tikz/flakes/item` if necessary). So you can make the scaling dependent on `#1`: If it's 0 then use scaling *a*, otherwise *b*.

The value `/tikz/flakes/level` is counting down (each *thing* will be drawn at level = 0), the value `/tikz/flakes/level'` is counting up.

You could just empty the `before split` style and use those levels and the item number to calculate, well, everything, on-the-fly.

---

I'm using my `ext.pgfkeys-plus` library (needs uptodate TikZ *and* [`tikz-ext`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-ext)) for a few PGFKeys “goodies”.

I'd recommend externalizing these graphics since this is not an efficient solution (starting with relying on heavy use of PGFKeys).

---

The size of the flakes are determined by the initial `drawDist` (here `1`), this value is used with the [*xyz* coordinate system](https://tikz.dev/tikz-coordinates#pgf.xyz) and is effected by any scaling but also by the vectors `x` and `y`.

I've also added a `\flakescreate` macro that groups its content and automatically issues `start` so that all values remain the same afterwards. (The first iteration isn't grouped.)

For applying different colors, I've added a `color i` where *i* stands for an integer number between 0 and 7 which apply a `draw` as well as a `fill` color:

```
\tikzset{
  /utils/temp/.style args={#1/#2}{color #1/.style={draw=#2, fill=#2!50}},
  /utils/temp/.list={0/violet, 1/red, 2/orange, 3/green!70!black,
                     4/cyan!70!black, 5/brown!70!black, 6/teal, 7/olive}}
```

You could almost the same by defining new colors (via `\colorlet`) where *i* is part of the name.

---

As commented, I've added a `start item` value that determines first item to be done, setting it to `start item = 1` skips the center piece. By swapping `end item` and `start item` the drawing order can be changed so that the middle piece is placed on top of all the others.

For more complex cases, the value `item list` can be set manually.

In this latest update, I've added the needed calculations for hexagons, septagons, octogons and nonagons where the last three use a custom and guesstimated scaling factor for the center piece.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepgfkeyslibrary{ext.pgfkeys-plus}
\makeatletter
\pgfqkeys{/handlers}{
  .foreach/.code={\let\pgfkeys@exp@call@\pgfkeys@exp@call
    \foreach\pgf@keys@temp in{#1}{\expandafter\pgfkeys@exp@call@\expandafter{\pgf@keys@temp}}}}
\makeatother
\newcommand*\flakesset{\pgfqkeys{/tikz/flakes}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{flakesDTS}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/flakes/draw to shift/.@cmd}#1\pgfeov}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{flakesDTD}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/flakes/draw to draw/.@cmd}#1\pgfeov}}
\newcommand*\flakescreate[1][]{\begingroup\flakesset{#1,start}\endgroup}
\flakesset{
  .code=\flakesset{#1}, tikz/.code=\tikzset{#1},
  draw to shift/.code={#1/2}, draw to draw/.code ={#1/2},
  drawDist/.initial=1, shiftDist/.initial=1,
  level/.initial=0, level'/.initial=0, item/.initial=0,
  start item/.initial=0, end item/.initial=3,
  item list/.initial={\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/flakes/start item},...,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/flakes/end item}},
  start/.style={level'=0, item=0, tikz=flakes/at start/.try, __do=0},
  __do/.style={
    /utils/TeX/ifnum={\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/flakes/level}=0}{__place={#1}}{
      level/.--, level'/.++, before split={#1},
      __split/.foreach/.expanded={\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/flakes/item list}}}},
  __split/.code={%
    \pgfkeyssetevalue{/tikz/flakes/item}{#1}%
    \tikzset{flakes/before do={#1}}%
    \flakesset{__do={#1}}%
    \tikzset{flakes/after do/.try={#1}}},
  __place/.code={\path[flakes/styling={#1}](0,0)to[flakes/path={#1}](0,0);},
  before split/.style={
    shiftDist/.evaluated=flakesDTS(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/flakes/drawDist}),
    drawDist/.evaluated =flakesDTD(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/flakes/drawDist}),
    level \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/flakes/level}/.try={#1},
    level \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/flakes/level'}'/.try={#1}}}
\tikzset{
  polygon path/.style 2 args={to path={
      plot[sharp cycle, samples at={1,...,#1}] (\x*360/#1:#2)}},
  polygon path*/.style 2 args={to path={
      plot[sharp cycle, samples at={1,...,#1}] ([shift={(\x*360/#1:{-.5*\pgflinewidth/sin((#1-2)/#1*90)})}]\x*360/#1:#2)}}}
\flakesset{
  poly shift/.style={shift=({#1}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/flakes/shiftDist})},
  if center/.style 2 args={/utils/TeX/ifnum={\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/flakes/item}=0}{#1}{#2}},
  set d2s and d2d/.style={draw to shift/.code={##1-#1}, draw to draw/.code={#1}},
  %
  polygon*/.style={polygon={#1}, path/.append style={polygon path*={#1}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/flakes/drawDist}}}},
  polygon/.style={
    start item = 0, end item/.pgfmath int = {#1},
    path/.style={polygon path={#1}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/flakes/drawDist}}},
    polygon calculation #1, at start/.append style={rotate=-90-180/#1},
    /utils/exec=\pgfmathsetmacro\valA{360/(#1)}\pgfmathsetmacro\valB{\valA/2},
    before do/.append style/.expanded={
      flakes/if center={\ifodd#1 rotate=\valB\fi}{flakes/poly shift=\valA*####1}}},
  polygon calculation 3/.style={set d2s and d2d = ##1/2},
  polygon calculation 4/.style={set d2s and d2d = ##1/3},
  polygon calculation 5/.style={set d2s and d2d = 0.3819660112501051*##1},
  polygon calculation 6/.style={set d2s and d2d = ##1/3},
  polygon calculation 7/.style={set d2s and d2d = 0.3079785283699041*##1, before do/.append style={flakes/if center={scale=1.5}{}}},
  polygon calculation 8/.style={set d2s and d2d = 0.2928932188134525*##1, before do/.append style={flakes/if center={scale=1.42}{}}},
  polygon calculation 9/.style={set d2s and d2d = 0.2577728010314408*##1, before do/.append style={flakes/if center={scale=2.07}{}}},
  Sierpinski carpet/.style={
    start item = 0, end item = 8,
    path/.style={to path={
                (-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/flakes/drawDist},-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/flakes/drawDist})
      rectangle ( \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/flakes/drawDist}, \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/flakes/drawDist})}},
    set d2s and d2d = ##1/3, before do/.append style={flakes/Sierpinski carpet/do ##1}},
  Sierpinski carpet/shift/.style 2 args={shift={(#1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/flakes/shiftDist},#2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/flakes/shiftDist})}},
  Sierpinski carpet/do 0/.code=,
  Sierpinski carpet/do 1/.style={flakes/Sierpinski carpet/shift=11},       Sierpinski carpet/do 2/.style={flakes/Sierpinski carpet/shift=01},
  Sierpinski carpet/do 3/.style={flakes/Sierpinski carpet/shift={-1}1},    Sierpinski carpet/do 4/.style={flakes/Sierpinski carpet/shift={-1}0},
  Sierpinski carpet/do 5/.style={flakes/Sierpinski carpet/shift={-1}{-1}}, Sierpinski carpet/do 6/.style={flakes/Sierpinski carpet/shift=0{-1}},
  Sierpinski carpet/do 7/.style={flakes/Sierpinski carpet/shift=1{-1}},    Sierpinski carpet/do 8/.style={flakes/Sierpinski carpet/shift=10},
}
\tikzset{
  /utils/temp/.style args={#1/#2}{color #1/.style={draw=#2, fill=#2!50}},
  /utils/temp/.list={0/violet, 1/red, 2/orange, 3/green!70!black,
                     4/cyan!70!black, 5/brown!70!black, 6/teal,
                     7/olive, 8/black, 9/yellow!50!black}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  row sep=+2mm, column sep=+2mm,
  row 5/.style={flakes={level=3, start item=1}},
  cells={
    /utils/exec={\useasboundingbox (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);},
    flakes={level/.pgfmath int=\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-1,
          polygon/.pgfmath int=\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn+2}}]
\matrix (m1) [flakes/styling/.style={fill/.pgfmath wrap={red!##1!blue}{#1/\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/flakes/end item}*100}}]{
  \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate \\
  \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate \\
  \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate \\
  \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate \\
  \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate \\
};
\matrix[flakes/styling/.style={color #1}, matrix anchor=west] at (m1.east){
  \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate \\
  \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate \\
  \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate \\
  \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate \\
  \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate & \flakescreate \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\tikz[x=+2cm, y=+2cm, flakes/styling/.style={color #1, draw=none}, row sep=+2mm, column sep=+2mm]\matrix{
  \flakescreate[Sierpinski carpet, level = 3] &
  \flakescreate[Sierpinski carpet, level = 3, start item = 1] &
  \flakescreate[Sierpinski carpet, level = 3, start item = 1, styling/.style={draw=black, fill=gray}] \\
  \flakescreate[level = 3, level 1/.append style={styling/.style=color #1}, polygon = 5] &
  \flakescreate[styling/.append style={draw, ultra thick, line join=round}, level = 1, polygon  = 3, start item = 3, end item = 0] &
  \flakescreate[styling/.append style={draw, ultra thick}, level = 1, polygon* = 3]
  \\};
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]

Comment: @ Qrrbrbirlbel Thank you very much for your answer. I am using the article documentclass. The output is too large to be displayed. Would you please exclude using matrix, so that I can apply reduced scaling for the tikzpicture to be able to view all the drawings.

Comment: @ Qrrbrbirlbel  I use these drawings within a document, to be edited as desired in different locations. How to predefine colours (for example 0/violet, 1/red, 2/orange, 3/green!70!black, 4/cyan!70!black, 5/brown!70!black, 6/teal, 7/olive), then chosen as needed. For example like this picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEDaP.jpg

Comment: @Hany I've updated my answer. The size of the diagrams can be changed via `scale` or the `x` and `y` keys since it uses the *xyz* coordinate system. You don't have to use a `\matrix`, just as with the `standalone` class, this was only used to arrange a few diagrams neatly.

Comment: @ Qrrbrbirlbel Thank you very much for your update. How to apply the colour choice to the drawings in the matrix, they are not affected by the update?

Comment: @Hany Yes, because I didn't apply the color scheme form them. Take a look at how the latter diagrams use a different `styling` then the matrix one. The color styles are defined in the lone `\tikzset` between the diagrams.

Comment: @ Qrrbrbirlbel I moved the tikzset to the beginning of the document, and applied to the matrix drawing this setting

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  flakes={
    styling/.append style=color #1},

I got the following picture.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/whv8n.jpg

I could not figure out how to add codes for hexagons and octagons, which were included in my post.

Comment: @ Qrrbrbirlbel Thank you very much for your time and concern.