# How to divide a circle into three equal circles using PGF/TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I want to draw the following figure:

[image]

The accepted answer of `SebGlav` from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/695145/how-to-draw-3-equal-circles-inside-a-circle-in-tikz-or-other-way/695437?noredirect=1#comment1726563_695437) gives some code.

The code (due to SebGlav):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\RadiusA}{8} %Define the radius of big-boundary circle
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\RadiusB}{\RadiusA/(1+2/sqrt(3))}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
         \draw[] (0,0) circle[radius=\RadiusA cm];
         \foreach \ang [count = \i from 1] in {90,210,330}
             \draw[] (\ang:\RadiusA-\RadiusB) coordinate (center-\i) circle[radius=\RadiusB cm];
         \pgfmathsetmacro{\RadiusC}{\RadiusB/(1+2/sqrt(3))}
         \foreach \i in {1,2,3}
             \foreach \ang in {90,210,330}
                 \draw[] ($(center-\i)+(\ang:\RadiusB-\RadiusC)$) circle[radius=\RadiusC cm];
         
         % Divide each small circle into 3 equal circles
         \foreach \i in {1,2,3}
             \foreach \ang in {90,210,330}
                 \foreach \j in {0,1,2}
                     \draw[] ($(center-\i)+(\ang:\RadiusB-\RadiusC)+(120*\j:\RadiusB/3)$) circle[radius=\RadiusB/6];
                     %this is the main governng equation for small circles
     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

plotted the following figure:

[image]

But the above figure can further be improved by improving the last governing equation

```
\draw[] ($(center-\i)+(\ang:\RadiusB-\RadiusC)+(120*\j:\RadiusB/5)$) circle[radius=\RadiusB/7];
```

as follows:

[image]

The later figure is much better, but still not what I require. We need to make sure the three small circles touch each other, as in the image in my question above.

I think we have to adjust the main governing equation at the end of the code. I appreciate suggestions.

Comment: If you had to construct the relevant part on paper using a circle, to draw circles, what would you do? How would you formulate, e.g. by words, the process? Translate that into Tikz for a small drawing first, and later into aboves code.

Comment: Well, aren't the smallest circles just again a repetition of the bigger thing: one circle containing three circles that touch the larger one? Can't you just repeat and scale this? The ratio of the two radii should always be the same.

Comment: @JasperHabicht, yes absolutely. I am trying to do it. But the  last command `\draw[] ($(center-\i)+(\ang:\RadiusB-\RadiusC)+(120*\j:\RadiusB/5)$) circle[radius=\RadiusB/7];` needs to be improved. I am unable to do it.

Comment: @MS-SPO, yes, I am doing that in the command `\draw[] ($(center-\i)+(\ang:\RadiusB-\RadiusC)+(120*\j:\RadiusB/5)$) circle[radius=\RadiusB/7];` but it is not giving as expected. Maybe I am making something wrong in the division of the circle

Comment: From [the formula of circle packing inside a circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle#:~:text=Circle%20packing%20in%20a%20circle%20is%20a%20two%2Ddimensional%20packing,the%20smallest%20possible%20larger%20circle.), we know that three unit circles are covered by a circle of radius (1+2/\sqrt(3))

Comment: Weird thing is that you've been provided with a recursive solution that you could use to do what you need. And as I said, the code I provided is *not* meant to be used in a recursive way, because you will need to adjust too much things in it. *But*, it could be adjusted for another iteration. Maybe by *learning* a bit from answers you get ;)

Comment: @SebGlav, as I said, the other beautiful code is not compiling into my Texstudio editor but your code is nicely compiling. So I decided to extend your code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An approach to this could be:

- calculate the ratio between the larger radius and the smaller radius of the circles, this happens to be `1/(1+(2/sqrt(3)))`.
- define a function in order to simplify things in the code.
- repeat and stick the function inside itself for smaller circles.

It should be possible to simplify this even further by self-referential (recursive) code, but I leave it as it is to make the approach more visible:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
        declare function={
            sr(\r) = \r/(1+2/sqrt(3));
        }
    ]

    \draw (0:0) circle[radius=5];
    
    \foreach \a in {90,210,330} {
        \draw (\a:{5-sr(5)}) circle[radius={sr(5)}];

        \begin{scope}[shift={(\a:{5-sr(5)})}]
        \foreach \a in {90,210,330} {
            \draw (\a:{sr(5)-sr(sr(5))}) circle[radius={sr(sr(5))}];

            \begin{scope}[shift={(\a:{sr(5)-sr(sr(5))})}]
            \foreach \a in {90,210,330} {
                \draw (\a:{sr(sr(5))-sr(sr(sr(5)))}) circle[radius={sr(sr(sr(5)))}];
            }
            \end{scope}
            
        }
        \end{scope}
    
    }

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

As stated above, it is possible to create a recursive function here (thanks to Qrrbrbirlbel for their input):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
        declare function={
            sr(\r,\i) = \r/((1+2/sqrt(3))^\i);
        }
    ]

    \draw (0:0) circle[radius=5];
    
    \NewDocumentCommand{\DrawThreeCircles}{ m O{0:0} O{0} m }{
        \begin{scope}[shift={(#2)}]
            \foreach \a in {90,210,330} {
                \draw (\a:{sr(#1,#3)-sr(#1,{#3+1})}) circle[radius={sr(#1,{#3+1})}];
                \ifnum#3<#4
                    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\x}{#3}
                    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\y}{#3+1}
                    \DrawThreeCircles{#1}[\a:{sr(#1,\x)-sr(#1,\y)}][\y]{#4}
                \fi
            }
        \end{scope}
    }

    % first argument: radius of largest circle
    % second argument: number of iterations
    \DrawThreeCircles{5}{3}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `sr(\r,\i) = \r/((1+2/sqrt(3))^\i)` for `sr(5, 0)`, `sr(5, 1)`, `sr(5, 2)` might be easier to handle and dynamically to adjust …

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Yes, this is a nice addition actually!

Comment: @JasperHabicht, unfortunately, there are  error message at the end `Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forge t a semicolon?` and `Package tikz Error: Cannot parse this coordinate`. I think there is sutle error

Comment: @learner You may need to use a proper and up to date LaTeX distribution. I copied and executed the above code and it compiled absolutely fine. So the issue is on your hand. Please don't assume that helpers and very well known members of TeX-SE made errors in the first place.

Comment: @SebGlav, agree it might be the problem in MikTeX, which I am saying since my last question. Regarding your last sentence, I don't agree with  because anybody can make mistake and  there can be error while copying and paste in general. I think the only gateway is your approach from my [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/695145/how-to-draw-3-equal-circles-inside-a-circle-in-tikz-or-other-way/695437?noredirect=1#comment1726563_695437)

Comment: @learner Yes, everybody can make mistakes. I typically compile the code a final time before posting it here. Still, sometimes mistakes happen. In this case, I cannot reproduce the error you state and I also cannot really say where this problem could come from.

Comment: @JasperHabicht, it is alright. I will check with different device